# Есть число как получить символ из таблице ASCII

Tags: java, ascii

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {       
        TreeMap< String ,Object> map= new TreeMap< String,Object>();        

        try {FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("src/ExamlesOfHashMapJava.txt");             
        int i =  -1;
        String v;
        while((i=fin.read())!=-1)   {           
            String key =String.valueOf(i);
            if(!map.containsKey(key)){map.put(key, 1);}
            else{
                int value = (int) map.get(key);
                map.put(key, value+1);
            }                   
        }       
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     Iterator<?> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
     while(it.hasNext())
     {       Entry< String ,Object> En = (Entry<String, Object>) it.next();
         String str = En.getKey().toString();   
         System.out.println(En.getKey()+"-->"+En.getValue());        

     }  

    }   

}
```

Я предполагал увидеть символы, а напротив - сколько раз они встречаются в тексте.
В результате:

```
10-->178
100-->210
101-->1004
102-->144
103-->130
104-->320
105-->476
106-->20
107-->76
108-->314
109-->226
110-->557
111-->567
112-->337
113-->7
114-->493
115-->488
116-->616
```

Как вернуть символы?

Answer (score 1):

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)   {   
    char ch = (char)i;
    String key =String.valueOf(ch);
    if(!map.containsKey(key)){map.put(key, 1);}
    else{
        int value = (int) map.get(key);
        map.put(key, value+1);
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант со `stream api`:

```
    List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(FILENAME)) {

        int i;
        while ((i = fin.read()) != -1)
            characterList.add((char) i);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    characterList
            .stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .forEach((symbol, count) -> System.out.println((symbol + " - " + count)));
```